# How to keep the original order (without sorting) when converting dictionary to list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary `{'16022000': 5172863.79, '21349000': 264853.56, '21362000': -5437717.35}` and created 4 lists for positive/negative key/values:

```
list({(g) for g, v in gv.items() if v >= 0})
list({(g) for g, v in gv.items() if v <= 0})
list({(v) for g, v in gv.items() if v >= 0})
list({(v) for g, v in gv.items() if v <= 0})
```

The results I got when printing the lists were:

```
['16022000', '21349000']
[264853.56, 5172863.79]
['21362000']
[-5437717.35]
```

Expecting:

```
['16022000', '21349000']
[5172863.79, 264853.56]
```

It seemed that list sorted numbers by value. How can I prevent that?

Comment: What are all the backslashses for?

Comment: @Maurice please check the before and after when you add code blocks. OP added backslashes to their code to have it render properly outside a code block, but those backslashes make the code nonsensical when they show up in a code block. If you don't feel like removing the backslashes, just leave a comment asking OP to use code blocks and direct them to [formatting help](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem 1

<s>Standard Python `dict` has no order; so no, you can't preserve the order, as there is none.</s>

Since Python 3.7 `dict` has order. (Thankyou [snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb), [Vikash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15544307/vikash))

## Problem 2

You are using "set comprehension" syntax: `{a for b in thing if condition}`

Sets similarly have no order.

## Solution

<s>Use an `OrderedDict` instead of a `dict`.</s>

Use a list comprehension instead of a set comprehension.

```py
gv = {'16022000': 5172863.79, '21349000': 264853.56, '21362000': -5437717.35}

[g for g, v in gv.items() if v >= 0]
[g for g, v in gv.items() if v <= 0]
[v for g, v in gv.items() if v >= 0]
[v for g, v in gv.items() if v <= 0]
```

## Remark

The only reason the order would matter to you is if you were going to pair the numbers back up after the fact. Have you considered:

```
[(g, v) for g, v in gv.items() if v >= 0]
```

or, as a dictionary

```
{g: v for g, v in gv.items() if v >= 0]
```

Comment: NB dicts preserve insertion order since 3.8.

Comment: Dict became ordered since 3.7 release, so we can simply use regular dictionary without even importing the ordereddict :)

Comment: It worked after I changed {} to []. I am really beginner on this and googled how to convert dictionary to list. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you noticed it, but you are actually storing the resultant elements in a set which you are then converting to a list.

Let me break down the code. Let's take line 3 as an example.

```
print(list({(v) for g, v in gv.items() if v >= 0}))
```

Now if you remove the list() constructor, you will notice the obvious.

```
print({(v) for g, v in gv.items() if v >= 0})
```

Output:

```
{264853.56, 5172863.79}
```

You can clearly see that the output is a set.

Why I'm telling you this is because sets are actually unordered. They store every elements in a random order. So, the output is in an order which dosen't make any sense.

So, to fix this problem, try not to store everything in a set, rather store it in a list itself.

```
print([v for g, v in gv.items() if v >= 0])
```

Now, the output will be more understandable:

```
[5172863.79, 264853.56]
```